# Apply Texture only on parts of Object with nodes

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I'm trying to model a beer bottle and I'm almost finished now. The only thing I still need to do is to apply the labels to the bottle. In Cycles I already mixed the Shaders for the glass and the label. My Problem is that the texture is applied to the whole bottle... It looks like this:
[image: ugly bottle]

I want to apply the Texture only to the body and the neck, because only these parts are unwrapped. I want the areas where usually no label is applied (in the image, you can see many tiny labels in these areas) , not to be textured!
this my node setup:

[image]

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this in two different ways

1. Either use two very similar materials, one with a texture other without, then use two distinct material slots for each. One for the parts with the logo the other for the parts without.
2. Reset and clear your UV coordinates for all faces of the bottle you want to keep without images. just enter edit mode, select all the faces where you don't want your image to appear and clear the UV coordinates. You can easily set them to X0,Y0 for example, in the UV editor by setting the cursor to 0,0 coordinate by pressing <kbd>.</kbd> and scaling them all with a factor of zero.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier way on doing that, but it only works if you don't use UV unwrapping.
You can just select parts of the mesh and in material settings hit assign, then you can select different parts of the mesh, chose new material and assign it to different part of the mesh. This meted is a lot easier and I use it a lot.

Also you can color the bottle and add labels later by assigning png images to the plane mesh and curving it as you need.